# React typescript useState string in object type error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types

Hello god developer friends

I have a Type error problem

Sorry update my question

**type**

```
interface IInfo {
  name: string;
  password: string;
}
```

**useState**

```
const [info, setInfo] = useState<IInfo>({
    name: '',
    password: '',
  });
```

**Error code**

```
useEffect(() => {
    setInfo({ name: text }); <- error
    console.log(info);
  }, [text]);
```

**Error message**

```
Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

**useInput**

```
import React, { useState, useCallback } from 'react';

export default () => {
  const [text, setText] = useState<string>();


  const getText = useCallback(
    (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
      const { value, placeholder } = e.target;
      setText(value);
    },
    [text],
  );
  return { text, getText};
};
```

Why name is error ?

I know problem is type definition

How defined useState type ?

Comment: Please show more about `text`

Comment: add to name in the interface definition a  undefined example (name: string | undefined; ) because you are not sendint the right data that;s why.

Comment: what is `text`  type in useState

Comment: Sorry text is custom hook value update my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your type definition is fine assuming you always want `name` and `password` properties on that object.

The problem with your update is that you're only providing `name`, not `name` and `password`, to `setInfo`. Unlike `setState` in `class` components, the setter you get from `useState` doesn't accept *partial* updates.

If you want to update `name` and `password` separately, you have (at least) two options:

1. Keep your current state member and use the callback form of the state setter and include the current `password` in the update:

   ```
   setInfo(({password}) => ({ name: text, password }));
   ```
2. Use two separate state members:

   ```
   const [name, setName] = useState("");
   const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
   ```

   Then use `setName` or `setPassword`.